# Trying to access another script in another GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have two GameObject, a door and the trigger. each GameObject has a script in each one, the trigger has PlayerDoorTrigger.js detects if the player enters the trigger. While the door has doorMove.js opens the door when clicked on.

I'm having a problem getting the boolean from PlayerDoorTrigger.js into an if statement from doorMove.js. Here are the two scripts below:

**doorMove.js**

```
var doorDynamic = false;

var playerTrigger:GameObject;


function Awake () {

}
function Start () {
    playerDoorTrigger.playerOnTrigger = true;
}

function Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        doorDynamic=true;
    }
    if(doorDynamic == true){
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime*128);
    }
    }

function OnCollisionEnter(doorCol:Collision){
    if(doorCol.gameObject.tag=="Walls"){
        Debug.Log("POP");
        doorDynamic = false;
    }   
}
```

**PlayerDoorTrigger**

```
public var playerOnTrigger = false;

function OnTriggerEnter(trigger:Collider){
    if(trigger.gameObject.tag=="Player"){
        playerOnTrigger=true;
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(trigger:Collider){
    if(trigger.gameObject.tag=="Player"){
        playerOnTrigger=false;
    }
}
```

Tried following the scripting reference in using GetComponent but no luck.

Please help me solve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your `PlayerDoorTrigger` component before you can use it.  Here is a quick example that assumes `PlayerDoorTrigger` and `doorMove` are attached to the same game object:

```
var playerDoorTrigger = GetComponent("PlayerDoorTrigger") as PlayerDoorTrigger;

if (playerDoorTrigger.playerOnTrigger) {
    Debug.Log("Huzzah, player trigger true.");
}
```

I'm assuming both of your scripts are in UnityScript (javascript).  If not, you need to [find other ways](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/280984/why-cant-i-access-my-c-class-from-javascript.html) of getting Unity to recognize the script classes, so you can assign variables of that type.

Comment: I will try this one. Will let you know if it worked. Thanks Jerdak.